# MP3のID3タグについて

Tags: mp3, file

お世話になります。

MP3内のタグについて、ID3v2 のファイルフォーマット情報ですが、一つ気になった点があるので、質問いたしました。

タイトルやアーティスト名などのデータを持っているフレーム部分ですが、そのフレームとフレームの間に空白が入ることは許されていますか？

つまり、タイトル名フレーム『tit2』のフレーム名の後、4バイト分のフレームサイズを表す
データが続きますが、そのサイズ分だけ進んだ先に、必ず次のフレームか実データ(MPEGフレーム)が続くのでしょうか？

空白が入った場合、読み取れるプレイヤーなどはありますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

そのような疑問から質問に至るのがちょっと理解できませんでした。

空白が含まれるかもと疑問を持つのであれば、

- 読み取りコードではスキップする機能を実装し、
- 書き込みコードでは（空白に未対応なソフトを考慮して）空白を埋め込まない

これで何の問題もないのでは？

Comment: いつもありがとうございます。考え方にもよると思いますが、世間一般ではどのようなルール付で行われているかです。今回のID3タグは、フォーマット違反でもただ読まれずに弾かれるだけですが、そのほかのファイルでは1バイトずれるだけで使えなくなることも珍しくないため、世間が空白の混じるファイルをどのくらい許容するのかを知ろうとしました。ほかのアプリでは違反になるのに、自分の組んだコードでは当たり前のように動く…というのも何か妙に感じたので。